# Enclose sql result in [

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query which will return a set of dates . I want to enclose these values inside '[]'.

My query is

```
   SELECT distinct  convert(varchar, track_empHours_date, 103)
          as track_empHours_date
    FROM tbl_track_empHours
    WHERE tbl_track_empHours.track_empHours_main_usr_id_fk = '268'
      AND track_empHours_date BETWEEN '5/09/2011' AND '5/15/2011'
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: Can you confirm track_empHours_date contains a value for your date range?

Comment: ... Why did you remove the square brackets from the original post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct '[' + convert(varchar, track_empHours_date, 103) + ']'
      as track_empHours_date
FROM tbl_track_empHours
WHERE tbl_track_empHours.track_empHours_main_usr_id_fk = '268'
  AND track_empHours_date BETWEEN '5/09/2011' AND '5/15/2011'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `QUOTENAME` for this.

```
SELECT 
   DISTINCT QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR, track_empHours_date, 103)) 
                                                      AS track_empHours_date  ...
```

Comment: Glad I read this - I wasn't aware of the `QUOTENAME` function.